# appending content to json file using php script

Tags: php, json

I am trying to append content to json file using php script.

output of file1 is

```
[
{"id":"filters","name":"filter_supptype_cp_01"}
]
```

output of file2 is

```
[
{"id":"drives","name":"hddcntrlr"},
{"id":"drives","name":"diskdrivedes"}
]
```

after appending the output should come as :

```
[
{"id":"filters","name":"filter_supptype_cp_01"},
{"id":"drives","name":"hddcntrlr"},
{"id":"drives","name":"diskdrivedes"}
]
```

but output is coming as : -

```
[
{"id":"filters","name":"filter_supptype_cp_01"}]
[{"id":"drives","name":"hddcntrlr"},
{"id":"drives","name":"diskdrivedes"}
]
```

Code that I have tried is:

```
$file = file_get_contents('makejson.json');
$data = json_decode($file);
$info[] = array('id'=>$attribute1, 'name'=>$sub_attr_name);
$newb = array_values((array)$info);
file_put_contents('makejson.json',json_encode($newb),FILE_APPEND);
```

please help!!!!

Comment: Don't append it. you should `get contents` and make `array` add `new array element` then overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Decode both files, append the array, encode again:

```
$existingData = json_decode(file_get_contents('file1.json'));
$newData = json_decode(file_get_contents('file2.json'));

$existingData = array_merge($existingData, $newData);
file_put_contents('file1.json', json_encode($existingData));
```

Comment: i provided solution with overwrite earlier, but above `questionnaire` mentioned, can't possible to overwrite. need `append` only.

Comment: I have yet to see a situation in which a file cannot be overwritten, but can be appended to. I rather suspect OP is confusing terms/is confusing you with their terms.

Answer (score 0):

The **array_push()** function inserts one or more elements to the end of an array.

**Your code :**

```
$file = file_get_contents('makejson.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($file);
array_push($tempArray, $data); // $data is your new data
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
file_put_contents('makejson.json', $jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this code to help to yoo after 6 ear.

```
if (isset($_POST['data']) && $_POST['data']) {

   $dbfile = file_get_contents('data.json');
   $data = json_decode($dbfile);
   unset($dbfile);

   $yourdata = $_POST['data'];

   $data[] = $yourdata;
   file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($data));
   unset($data);   }
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to `append` array. You need to `overwrite` it.

Try like:

```
$file = file_get_contents('makejson.json');
$data = json_decode($file);
$data[] = array('id'=>$attribute1, 'name'=>$sub_attr_name);
file_put_contents('makejson.json',json_encode($data)); //Overwrite it
```

It will overwrite with new array.

Comment: I cant overwrite. I need to append the contents. is there a way?

Comment: if you got the `content` and added array after decode. then overwrite with newly added array data. so what makes difference in your code....?

Comment: While, yes, this *can* work, it seems like a really bad idea. You're just *assuming* you know the contents of the file and can manipulate them blind. A single trailing newline in the file will already break all this, which may happen if you ever manipulate the file by hand.

Comment: @deceze! sir agree with you, please suggest better way if we can implement.

Comment: @yash I tried the above code that you mentioned. But it didnt work. so wt i did was. I got all the content of both file in two arrays and  and then merged two arrays and wrote it into file using file_put_contents.

Comment: @KritiSingh Earlier i answered the same what you did.